# Parsing a json output with dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x

Hello my JSON file looks like this :

```
{
    'hits' : 3, 
    'results' : [{
        'part' : {
            'id' : '123', 
            'name' : 'to go', 
            'manu' :{ 
                'name' :'xyz'
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

how do i get :

1. `hits : 3`
2. `results_id : 123`
3. `results_name : to go`
4. `manu_name : xyz`

Looking to write a python key-value pair for a loop... Not getting please advise.

My keys are `hits` and `results`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: for key, value in output.items(): print ("key", "values")

Comment: Please be more descriptive. What is `output`? `for key, value in output.items():` is just the start of a loop....

Comment: @brooklinite81 Please edit your question and mention your desired output in proper code formatting. Like: `hits: 3` and so on.

Comment: To use Python's JSON library, the JSON strings must be valid JSON, which means the use of double quotes for property names and string values. Single quotes are not accepted. Replace all the single quotes in your file with double quotes before proceeding otherwise, you will get the following error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dout = {}
#din = json.load("file.json") #read from json
din = {'hits' : 3, 'results' : [{'part' : {'id' : '123', 'name' : 'to go', 'manu' :{ 'name' :'xyz'}}}]}
for part in din['results']:
    for p, data  in part.items():
         dout['hits'] = din['hits']
         dout['results_id'] = data['id']
         dout['results_name'] = data['name']
         dout['manu_name'] = data['manu']['name']

print(dout)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, update the string as follows to make it valid JSON:

```
{"hits" : 3, "results" : [{"part" : {"id" : "123", "name" : "to go", "manu" :{ "name" :"xyz"}}}]}
```

Assuming that's the content of your text file, proceed as follows:

```
import json

data = {}

with open("stackOverflow/brooklinite81.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

data
```

which renders:

```
{'hits': 3, 'results': [{'part': {'id': '123', 'name': 'to go', 'manu': {'name': 'xyz'}}}]}
```

Now, you can create a dictionary the way you wanted it as follows:

```
res = {'hits' :data['hits'], 
       'results_id': data['results'][0]['part']['id'], 
       'manu': data['results'][0]['part']['manu']['name'] 
       }

res
```

which renders as:

```
{'hits': 3, 'results_id': '123', 'manu': 'xyz'}
```